# When is $(X, \mathcal{T}_{trivial})$ Hausdorff?

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

> When is $(X, \mathcal{T}_{trivial})$ Hausdorff?

Recall: $\mathcal{T}_{trivial} = \{\varnothing, X\}$

I want to say that this space is Hausdorff is $X$ is a singleton

But I can't actually produce two open sets that satisfy the condition:

> $\forall x,y \in X$, there exists disjoint $U, V \in
> \mathcal{T}_{trivial}$ such that $x \in U$ and $y \in V$

Suppose $X = \{x\}$, then yes we have a $x \in U = \{x\}$, but do we have $y \in \varnothing$, since $\varnothing$ is empty?, or is the condition trivially satisified since there is only one point?

Comment: You're almost right: a space with the trivial topology is Hausdorff if and only if it either a singleton or empty. And your definition of Hausdorff is slightly off: it should start "for any two **distinct** points $x$ and $y$ ...". (As is, taking $y=x$ shows no non-empty space can satisfy the definition.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no pairs of **distinct** points $x$ and $y$ to test the Hausdorff hypothesis on. This makes the statement voidly true:

Hausdorffness of the space $(X,\mathscr{T})$ means (put formally):

$$\forall x\in X \forall y \in Y: (x \neq y) \rightarrow (\exists U \in \mathscr{T} \exists V \in \mathscr{T} : (U \cap V = \emptyset) \land (x \in U) \land (y \in V))$$

The implication is true because the antecedent $x \neq y$ is always false (and false implies anything is true).

Answer (score 1):

I think the question is easier to solve if we write the negative of the statement:

> A topological space $(X,\mathcal T)$ **is not** Hausdorff if $\exists x,y\in X$ with $x\neq y\,$ s.t. $\forall U,V\in\mathcal T$ with  $x\in U$ and $y\in V$ then $U\cap V\neq\emptyset$

Alternatively we can write:

> A topological space $(X,\mathcal T)$ **is** Hausdorff if $\nexists x,y\in X$ with $x\neq y\,$ s.t. $\forall U,V\in\mathcal T$ with  $x\in U$ and $y\in V$ then $U\cap V\neq\emptyset$